# How to center FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

**I am trying to center a FlowLayoutPanel** because I am using it my application in *different computers*. So I am having some problems because, for example, in my screen works fine but in another screen of a different computer the flowlayoutpanel is in the right side of the screen.

What I am doing to try to center this flowlayoutpanel is the following:

```
public MainPrinc()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            flowlayoutPl.Location = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - flowlayoutPl.Size.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height / 2 - flowlayoutPl.Size.Height / 2);
        }
```

But this is not working, what could I do? Thanks in advance.

**EDIt:** 
*How looks in my screen*:

[My computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFAW8.png)

*How looks in another computer*:

[Another computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR0st.png)

Comment: How are you switching screens? Dragging?

Comment: @Trey sorry, maybe my explanation is not good, what I wanted to say is that this application is used in different computers, my computer and another computer with a bigger or smaller screen

Comment: The reason I ask is that I would personally put that code in the move event handler, or the form resize.  Your center code looks good, but is the layout panel inside another container?

Comment: yes, sorry, is in a form @Trey

Comment: Mind showing screenshot of what it looks like?  I cannot tell much from the code you have shared.

Comment: You have code in the constructor and the monitor may not be setup.  I would move code to the Load method instead of in the constructor.

Comment: @Trey updated the post with screens :)

Comment: @jdweng is not a problem at this moment that

Comment: You need to set the left property.  The left is is probably left at a value from a previous application.

Comment: Left property? of the flowLayoutPanel? @jdweng

Comment: This may be a timing issue. Try moving the code to the Shown event. Also: To keep a control centered one will either have to repeat the code upon Resize or remove all(!) anchors..

Comment: Typical dpiAware-ness issue.  This code belongs in the Load event handler, not the constructor.  At that point the window has been rescaled from its design size.  You might also have a problem when the design size of the form is too large to fit the screen on the target machine before rescaling, the window will then be too small.  Doesn't look like that's the case.

Comment: So reading the comments, looks like the problem comes from the code that is not in the load and is in the constructor. I am new with C# so ... should I do a new method and put this line?

Comment: Every control has four properties Left, Top, Width, Height.

Comment: Easiest way is to put this in the center column of a three column TableLayoutPanel, where the column widths are 50%,auto-fit-content,50% respectively.  No code required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your code in the **Load** event handler like this:

```
private void MainPrinc_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            flowlayoutPl.Location = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - flowlayoutPl.Size.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height / 2 - flowlayoutPl.Size.Height / 2);
        }
```